# Having problems replacing data in array

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array, scanf

For a project I have to do, I have to list a set of classes, have the user select which class to use, and print out a weekly schedule for them for the semester. (Same program as the first question I asked.) However, I seem to run into a problem when I try to print out a weekly schedule. (The program is pretty lengthy, at least with the experience I have in C.)

```
struct course
{
 int index;
 char name[7];
 char day[4];
 int hours,houre,mins,mine;
 char ap[3];
 int credit;
};
struct course whcl[]={ {0,"MATH1","MWF",7,8,30,50,"AM",5},
                       {1,"MATH2","MWF",9,10,00,20,"AM",5},
                       {2,"CHEM1","MW ",2,6,30,50,"PM",5},
                       {3,"PHYS4","TTH",4,6,00,45,"PM",4},
                       {4,"ENGR1","M  ",9,10,30,20,"AM",1},
                       {5,"ENGR2","TTH",10,12,00,15,"PM",3},
                       {6,"ENGR3","MW ",11,12,00,15,"PM",3}};
int choice[15],i,j,k,num,z,s;
void printout(int z); //(To be put in when I fix the function)

int main(void)
{
 char l[8][3]={{"st"},{"nd"},{"rd"},{"th"},{"th"},{"th"},{"th"},{"th"}};
 printf("                 Fall Schedule\n");
 printf("Index  Course  Day        Time       Credit\n");
 printf("-------------------------------------------\n");
 for(i=0;i<7;i++)
 {
  printf("  %i    %s  %s    %i%i:%i%i-%i%i:%i%i%s     %i\n",
          whcl[i].index,whcl[i].name,whcl[i].day,
          whcl[i].hours/10,whcl[i].hours%10,
          whcl[i].mins/10,whcl[i].mins%10,
          whcl[i].houre/10,whcl[i].houre%10,
          whcl[i].mine/10,whcl[i].mine%10,
          whcl[i].ap,whcl[i].credit);
 }
 printf("How many classes would you like to take?: ");
 scanf("%i",&num);
 for(i=0;i<num;i++)
 {
  printf("Select the %i%s class using the index: ",i+1,l[i]);
  scanf("%i",&choice[i]);
 }
 printf("The classes you have selected are:\n");
 printf("Index  Course  Day       Time       Credit\n");
 printf("-------------------------------------------\n");
 for(i=0;i<num;i++)
 {
  s=choice[i];
  printf("  %i    %s   %s   %i%i:%i%i-%i%i:%i%i%s    %i\n",
          whcl[s].index,whcl[s].name,whcl[s].day,
          whcl[s].hours/10,whcl[s].hours%10,
          whcl[s].mins/10,whcl[s].mins%10,
          whcl[s].houre/10,whcl[s].houre%10,
          whcl[s].mine/10,whcl[s].mine%10,
          whcl[s].ap,whcl[s].credit);
 }
 printf("Your weekly schedule for Fall is:\n");
 printf("    Time     Monday   Tuesday   Wednesday   Thursday   Friday\n");
 printout(z);
 return 0;
}

void printout(int z)
{
 int start,starti,end,endi,num;
 int slot[25][6];
 for(i=0;i<24;i++)
  for(j=0;j<5;j++)
   slot[i][j]=99;
 for(i=0;i<num;i++)
 {
  if ((whcl[choice[i]].day)=="MWF")//I think the problem is here.
  {
   start=whcl[choice[i]].hours*60+whcl[choice[i]].mins;
   end=whcl[choice[i]].houre*60+whcl[choice[i]].mine;
   starti=(start-450)/30;
   endi=(end-450)/30;
   for(j=starti;j<=endi;j++)
    slot[j][1]=slot[j][3]=slot[j][6]=whcl[choice[i]].index;
  }
 }
 for(i=0;i<24;i++)
 {
  printf("%i%i:%i%i-%i%i:%i%i ",
         (450+(i-1)*30)/60/10,(450+(i-1)*30)/60%10,
         (450+(i-1)*30)%60/10,(450+(i-1)*30)%60%10,
         (450+(i-1)*30+30)/60/10,(450+(i-1)*30+30)/60%10,
         (450+(i-1)*30+30)%60/10,(450+(i-1)*30+30)%60%10);
  for(j=0;j<4;j++)
  {
   if (slot[i][j]!=99) //Use Note here
    printf(" %s       ",whcl[choice[i]].name);
   else
    printf("");
  }
  printf("\n");
 }
return;
}
```

When I print out the schedule, the only thing that comes up is the time. Everything else is blank. I think it's due to my trying to replace the slot array with something other than 99. If you plan on running this program, please use 2 the amount of classes you want to take, and use 0 and 1 for the index on the class choice. (I don't have any if statements and whatnot to take into account the other classes the user might have chosen.) Here's a photo of what I'm trying to do for my program. http://postimg.org/image/3tlgtwu9h/ I used paint to put in the boxes on the schedule to visually see the different arrays as I was coding.

Note: If you change the if statement to [i][j]==99 You can see the "Class" being printed on the table, however it fills up the entire array slot, which confirms my thought that I messed up on trying to replace data in the array. Also, I filled it up with 99 to make 99 associated with blank spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if ((whcl[choice[i]].day)=="MWF")` //I think **the problem is here**.

Correct, you need to use `strcmp` to compare strings, not `==`

Try:
`if (strcmp(whcl[choice[i]].day,"MWF") == 0)`

Equality as `==` will check if pointers are the same so you could have:

`char * a = "MTW"; char *b = a` and then `a == b` would be true

Comment: I replaced my line with the line you provided. However when I ran it, it still gave me the same output. And when I looked up the strcmp, I read that it needed <string.h> but even added that didn't change anything.

Comment: @Kesakor  - have you stepped it through a debugger?

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean by debugger. I use the terminal in Ubuntu to GCC the file.

Comment: @Kesakor if you look into `gdb` it will let you load your program, step through it line by line, and you can print out all the vakues of variables as you step through

Comment: Ok, your function worked well. The problem was I declared num a second time in my function section despite making it a global variable. That's what caused the loop to be skipped.